# gt summary chi-square result different from chisquare.test

Tags: r, gt

I ran a chi-square test twice and got different result:

(1)gt summary

```
table1_demographic_data <-
  subsetted.demographic %>%
  tbl_summary(by= post_covid_dic,
              missing = "no",
              missing_text= "NA",
              type= list(comorbid_HTN ~ "dichotomous"),
              statistic = list(
                all_continuous() ~ "{mean}?{sd}",
                all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"), percent = "row") %>%
  add_p() %>%
  modify_header(label = "**Variable**", statistic ~ "**Test 
Statistic**") %>%
  modify_fmt_fun(statistic ~ style_sigfig) %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  bold_p() %>%
  modify_caption("table 1: Demographic characteristics")

table1_demographic_data
```

x2=4.3 p=0.039

(2) chisquare.test

```
chisq.test(subsetted.demographic$post_covid_dic, 
subsetted.demographic$comorbid_HTN)
```

results: x2=3.8076 p=0.05

Can anyone explain the different results?

Thanks

Comment: You need to give more information. What data? How did you do a chi-square test with `gt`?  What function? What options?

Comment: I edited the question. hope it is clearer now

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `gt_summary::add_p` says it defaults to a chi-squared test with no continuity correction, whereas `stats::chisq.test` defaults to using a continuity correction.

If you want the continuity correction, I think you can add the argument
`test.args = all_tests("chisq.test") ~ list(correct = TRUE)` to `gt_summary::add_p`. If you don't want it, add the argument `correct=FALSE` to `stats::chisq.test`

Comment: Many thanks. Based on my results, these indeed seems the case